# How to create "list of algorithms" at the end of the pdf file

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

To create the list of algorithms I have created a tex-file:

```
\cleardoublepage
\ihead[]{List of Algorithms}
\listofalgorithms
\addtocontents{loa}{\def\string\figurename{Algorithm}}
```

and in the main file added it as `\input{list_of_algorithms.tex}`

It works, but I get

[image]

I expect to see a table /list, How to fix it?

Comment: Have you looked into the `tocloft` package?

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? Because this does not show the configurations of your document.

Comment: In particular, there is more than one package which produces a `\listofalgorithms`, and it looks like you have a custom `\l@algorithm`